# LINQ to Entities - DISTINCT on one column

Tags: linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

Is there a way to write following query with Linq to Entities (or Entity SQL, or Method Syntax, or any other way, but I would like to achieve it with Linq to Entities):

```
SELECT DISTINCT Column1
FROM Table1
```

I'm using Entity Framework 4. Of course I don't want to use Distinct method that filters data after data is fetched from database.

thanks,Pawel

Comment: The `Distinct` method actually adds `DISTINCT Column1` to your query generated

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use something like

```
db.Table1.Select(t => t.Column1).Distinct()
```

As Munim mentioned in his comment, the Distinct() method does add the DISTINCT to the query. So resulting SQL query will be

```
SELECT [Distinct1].[Column1] AS [Column1]
  FROM ( SELECT DISTINCT 
    [Extent1].[Column1] AS [Column1]
    FROM [dbo].[Table1] AS [Extent1]
  )  AS [Distinct1]
```

Answer (score 4):

For distinct by column, use this extension:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> DistinctBy<T, TKey>(this IEnumerable<T> items, Func<T, TKey> property)
{
    return items.GroupBy(property).Select(x => x.First());
}
```

Comment: Note* using this method will mean the statement will no longer remain IQueryable.