# Entity Framework is executing too many queries

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, performance, entity-framework

I need to find distinct Campaigns of a particular user. A User has CodeRights, CodeRights contain Codes and Codes contain Campaign. Here is the CodeRight class

```
public class SmartCodeRight
{
        [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
        public long UserId { get; set; }
        public virtual User User { get; set; }

        [Key, Column(Order = 2)]
        public long CodeId { get; set; }
        public virtual SmartCode Code { get; set; }

        public CodeRight CodeRight { get; set; }
}
```

I would write the following SQL for this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM campaigns 
WHERE campaignid IN (SELECT DISTINCT campaignid  
                     FROM smartcodes t1 
                     INNER JOIN smartcoderights t2 ON t1.codeId = t2.codeId
                     WHERE t2.userid = @userId)
```

Using EF I am writing this code:

```
var v = user.CodeRights.Select(r => r.Code.Campaign).Distinct().ToList();
```

Now on profiling I am seeing that EF is executing 2 SQL queries for every CodeRight present.

I have also calculated the time of entire execution and **EF takes ~400 ms while using ADO.Net it's only ~8**.

Now my question is that if EF is really this slow or I'm doing something wrong?

**Edits**

Following two blocks are being executed for every CodeRight

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT 
[Extent1].[CodeId] AS [CodeId], 
[Extent1].[CodeTitle] AS [CodeTitle], 
[Extent1].[CodeContent] AS [CodeContent], 
[Extent1].[CreatedOn] AS [CreatedOn], 
[Extent1].[IsActive] AS [IsActive], 
[Extent1].[Deleted] AS [Deleted], 
[Extent1].[OwnerId] AS [OwnerId], 
[Extent1].[Tags] AS [Tags], 
[Extent1].[CampaignId] AS [CampaignId]
FROM [dbo].[SmartCodes] AS [Extent1]
WHERE [Extent1].[CodeId] = @EntityKeyValue1',N'@EntityKeyValue1 bigint',@EntityKeyValue1=24
go
```

and

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT 
[Extent1].[CampaignId] AS [CampaignId], 
[Extent1].[Name] AS [Name], 
[Extent1].[Description] AS [Description], 
[Extent1].[AdminId] AS [AdminId]
FROM [dbo].[Campaigns] AS [Extent1]
WHERE [Extent1].[CampaignId] = @EntityKeyValue1',N'@EntityKeyValue1 int',@EntityKeyValue1=12
go
```

Comment: Can you show the code executing the query?  This question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8473705/linq-to-entities-distinct-on-one-column) indicates that EF should be generating a proper query using `DISTINCT`

Comment: The trade-off for ORM's is that they are "chatty".  Most of the time the performance is "good enough".  But they are chatty.  But you spend less time writing custom ORM code.  Pick a poison.  One think you can do is see how EF issues the query and see if there is an index that is worth adding.

Comment: @w.brian Please see the edits.

Comment: You haven't set those items up as foreign keys, not sure if that makes a difference though.

Comment: @mattytommo All foreign keys are properly configured. I have crosschecked the database.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should spend time looking at [Fetch Plans for Entity Framework](http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/ado_net/A-Feature-driven-Comparison-of-Entity-Framework-and-NHibernate-Fetch-Plans.aspx). In order for EF to perform the join, you'll have to use the `Include` keyword.

It'll have to be part of your initial query when you get your `user` object:

```
var user = context.Users
    .Include("CodeRights.Code")
    .Include("CodeRights.Campaign")
    .FirstOrD‌​efault(u => u.Id == id);
```

Comment: CodeRights is a collection of type CodeRight so can't have "Include" there.

Comment: The `Include` needs to be a part of the query that returns the user, something like `var user = context.Users.Include("CodeRights.Code").Include("CodeRights.Campaign").FirstOrDefault(u => u.Id == id);`

Comment: @DmitryStarosta Good shout, didn't spot that. Updated :)

Comment: Did like this
`var v = db.SmartCodeRights.Where(r => r.UserId == user.UserId).Include(r => r.Code).Include(r => r.Code.Campaign).Select(r => r.Code.Campaign).Distinct().ToList();`
and just a single query now. Didn't want to include in the first query as it'll unnecessarily bring data.